# 403 Forbidden after successfully installing Ghost

Tags: node.js, ssh, port, ghost-blog

I have been spending days figuring out how to install the viral [Ghost](http://ghost.org) platform, and experienced numerous errors. Luckily, I have managed to install it - Ghost gives me a positive `Ghost is running...` message in SSH after I've done `npm start --production`. However, when I browse to my website - http://nick-s.se - Apache displays its default page and when I go to the ghost login area - /ghost, the site returns a 403 Forbidden.

P.S. I have specifically installed Ghost on a different port than the one Apache is running on. I don't know what's going on...

**Update** - I have found out that I can access my Ghost installation by adding the port number 2368 which I've configured in the config.js. Now, however my problem is - how can I run Ghost without using such ports?...

Comment: did you attempt connecting to that port? [`http://nick-s.se:2368`](http://nick-s.se:2368)

Comment: I went by your link and yes, Ghost works! At least I know my installation is partially correct. But how can I make it so that Ghost runs without such ports? So I can have a clean URL?

Comment: Port 80 is the default HTTP port. You will either have to find a solution where requests go through apache on port 80 to your Ghost app on another port; or you turn Apache off port 80; or you may be able to use a DNS solution to point requests to another port (dunno)

Comment: Thanks. I already found a suitable solution without taking too much pains - use an htaccess to transparently send traffic to port 2368. Here's the full [how-to](http://blog.peterschmalfeldt.com/using-ghost-on-port-80-when-its-already-in-use/)

Comment: same problem here and your blog is now private. can you share the solution?

Comment: @EsseTi Use the WayBack Machine to access his site. Here's a link - https://web.archive.org/web/20140414053539/http://blog.peterschmalfeldt.com/using-ghost-on-port-80-when-its-already-in-use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tell your browser you want to connect to the port Ghost is running on: [`http://nick-s.se:2368`](http://nick-s.se:2368)

Answer (score 0):

So a few things, based on visiting:

1) It seems Apache isn't proxying the request onward to Ghost. Are you sure that you've configured it properly?

2) It also looks like Apache doesn't have access to the directory that you set as root. This shouldn't be necessary anyway if proxying is set up correctly, but could become an issue later if you wanted to use apache to serve things like the static assets.

If you are open to nginx instead of Apache, I have written a how to on this: [link](http://slingingcode.com/how-to-configure-ghost/). You can skip the section on configuring Nginx. Otherwise, still might be useful if you figure out the conversion of rules from Nginx to Apache.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any other sites running on your VPS you can just turn apache off and not have to deal with apache proxying the request to port 2368 and have Ghost run on port 80.  If your VPS is running CentOS you can check out this [how to](http://www.howtoinstallghost.com/how-to-setup-bluehost-vps-for-ghost-blog/) on disabling apache and running Ghost on port 80.

Comment: Yes, I know that. My question is - how can I run Ghost WITH Apache, as I have 10 sites on the server which use Apache. I tried editing httpd.conf by adding a VirtualHost entry, but it doesn't seem to work for me...